# Quantifying + comparing the effects of conditioning on Shannon entropy

Tags: entropy, information-theory, uncertainty, mutual-information

I'm working on a project that compares how predictable/unpredictable individuals' actions are in terms of how they transition between actions. We consider their actions to part of a first-order Markov chain, where $X$ is a random variable describing their present action and $Y$ describes their next action. We calculate $P(Y|X)$ based on observed data and then compute $H(Y|X)$ for each person.

Ideally, we'd like to be able to compare the transitional/behavioral unpredictability between individuals. Our concern is: we have $n$ human-defined "types" of actions, so some individuals engage in the full set of actions while some only perform a subset of them. Thus, the "maximum" possible conditional entropy differs between people: $|Y| \neq n$ for everyone. This makes me think that $H(Y|X)$ can't be compared between individuals as-is.

My first idea was to use Mutual Information instead because it accounts for how much uncertainty is contained in $Y$ in the first place: $I(X;Y)=H(Y)-H(Y|X)$. However, the maximum value of $H(Y)$ is also still affected the number of action categories. Instead, I'm thinking of proposing that we compare $\frac{H(Y|X)}{H(Y)}$ between participants: the percentage of uncertainty *left* in $Y$ after viewing $X$. Thus, we can compare how informative a person's present action is when predicting their subsequent action; less predictable people will have a greater percentage of the original entropy $H(Y)$ remaining than more predictable people.

However, I've been unable to find any mention/usage of the quantity $\frac{H(Y|X)}{H(Y)}$ in other papers. Is there a term for this value, or is there a reason why I can't find it anywhere? The closest comparable quantity I could find divides by maximum possible entropy instead ($\log(n)$), but this makes me uncomfortable because it requires us to assume that each person is only capable of the actions seen in the data and not all $n$ action categories.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: $\frac{H(Y|X)}{H(Y)}$ is just $1-U(Y|X)$ where $U$ is the uncertainty coefficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_coefficient.

The actual formula is $$\frac{I(X;Y)}{H(Y)} = \frac{H(Y)-H(Y|X)}{H(Y)}$$ and describes the fraction of information/bits you can predict from seeing $Y$. It's a form of normalized mutual information.

I cannot believe how easy it was to find *after* typing my question up